# Getting Error Message While Saving Emojis With Text Data

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, xamarin.forms

I am trying to save emojis along with text data to `postgressql database with version PostgreSQL 9.4.15` and encoding `UTF8` in my `Spring MVC Web application`. I had used database Default collation in `utf8.` I am able to save the emojis along with text data in the database, but while retrieving the rows using my dao method, it is showing an error like below.

> Invalid character data was found.  This is most likely caused by
>   stored data containing characters that are invalid for the character
>   set the database was created in.  The most common example of this is
>   storing 8bit data in an SQL_ASCII database.

**My friend end is xamarin forms PCL project, Is there any way to fix this issue from front end itself or any solution from the backend?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: use a different character set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to solve this issue from the front end. Since your front end is xamarin forms you need to encode the contents before sending it into the server and decode the content when you retrieve.

```
 System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(*string*); // Encode
 System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(*string*); // Decode
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option to try: Client needs to encode message in base 64 before sending to server and decode back to base 64 before returning the data back to client. This should make the emojis work on the client applications.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to refer the following article [The ultimate guide to Emojis](https://smellyc0de.wordpress.com/2018/04/07/the-ultimate-guide-to-emojis/) to get some insight in to how this can be handled.